# Performing calculations on multiple nested python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Trying to create a dict comprehension by comparing two nested dictionaries of similar size and subtracting the last value of the lowest nested dictionary.  Only values != 0 will be included in the dictionary.

```
d1 = {1: {'a':10,'b':20,'c':10}}
d2 = {1: {'a':30,'b':40,'c':10}}
```

matchKeys = d1.keys() & d2.keys()

```
new = {}
for k in matching_keys:
    if not d1[k] == d2[k]:
        for d1_key, d1_value in d1[k].items():
            for d2_key, d2_value  in d2[k].items():
                new[k][d2_key] = (d2_value-d1_value)
```

also tried:

```
d3 = {k: {d2_key:(d2_value-d1_value) for d2_key, d2_value in d2.items()} for d1_key, d1_value in d1[k].items() for k in matching_keys if not d1[k] == d2[k]}
```

I'm expecting:

```
d3 = {1: {'a':20,'b':20}}
```

Comment: You said "similar" and not "same". So if ```d1 = {1: {'a':10,'b':20,'c':10}}
d2 = {1: {'a':30,'b':40,'c':10}}``` was ```d1 = {1: {'a':10,'b':20,'c':10}}
d2 = {1: {'a':30,'b':40,}}```, would this still work? Just want to clarify.

Comment: What Is the output you have got right now

Comment: To clarify the dict would be the same all except the nested values in lower level dictionary.    The dict comprehension complains about the assignment of (d2_value-d1_value)  to the d2_key  throwing a TypeError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `matchkeys` only holds the keys on the first level of the dicts. You need to to get the keys of each level as you move into the dictionaries. It might be easier to think of this as a recursive function. Then you can just pass the nested dicts back into the function.

Something like:

```
d1 = {1: {'a':10,'b':20,'c':10}}
d2 = {1: {'a':30,'b':40,'c':10}}

def filterDifs(d1, d2):
    d = {}
    matchKeys = d1.keys() & d2.keys()
    for k in matchKeys:
        if isinstance(d1[k], dict) and isinstance(d2[k], dict):
            d[k] = filterDifs(d1[k], d2[k])
        else:
            try:
                if d1[k] - d2[k] != 0:
                    d[k] = d1[k] - d2[k]
            except TypeError:
                pass
    return d

filterDifs(d1, d2)
```

**Result:**

```
{1: {'b': -20, 'a': -20}}
```

This will ignore attempts to subtract incompatible types, but if you wanted to add some sort of value in those cases you could in the `except` block:

```
except TypeError:
    d[k] = "Some error value"
```

Comment: What i noticed about this solution is that if all the nest values are equal it still returns a dictionary with the higher level key and an empty values.  How can the function simply return None if all values are equal?

Comment: replaced the return statement with return {key:val for key, val in diffs.items() if val}